# Multiple responses using Celery in Flask application?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm developing a **Slack** application where I have to query a database using an external API and then display some results to the user. Thing is, querying this database takes some time and Slack needs a response within 3s or it gives a **Timeout error**.

I've thought about using **Celery** to giver some answer to Slack while another function queries the database, but I'm struggling to write code that handles those multiple responses.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)

celery = Celery(app.name, broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@celery.task
def hello():
    return 'Display some results :)'

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def main():
    hello.delay()
    return 'Querying database...'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

But when I run this application, I only get `'Querying database'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling `hello.delay()` is starting a task and moving on. I believe it returns an `AsyncResult`. Using celery like you are above will not gain you anything.

Comment: How should I use this AsyncResult to display the return value of hello() after already returning main()?

Comment: There's no "easiest" way to do it .. but what I've seen done is you send a websocket-ID that represents the person who did the POST, then when the job is done you can assign a callback that sends its response via websocket to the client.

Comment: Follow this [tutorial on flask+gevent+websockets](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) and you'll be on the right path.